# Cann't ping nw from vm (debian)

Tags: linux, networking, debian, linux-mint, ping

Okay so i got as an VM debian 9. 
As OS i use Linux Mint 19.1.
I used nat for it

Debian config:
ip: 192.168.11.2 /24
gw: 192.168.11.1

Linux mint config:
ip vmnet8: 192.168.11.1 /24
gw: unknown

ip wlan_port: 172.18.200.166
gw: 172.18.203.254

I can ping from Linux Mint into the Internet.
From the Debian Server i can ping every interface of my PC, but i cann't ping any further (f.i. ping 8.8.8.8 fails)

Does anyone got an idea?

EDIT:
Okay it works if i set the gw of the debian to 192.168.11.2 (the ip oc then smth else). Idk why but it works. (The VMnet8 IF is still 192.168.11.1)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want your host server (Mint) to route the traffic to the Internet. Default, routing should not be enabled.

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

should enable routing (ip forwarding).

Comment: ty for the answer but well i made it working by setting the gw of the debian to 192.168.11.2.

Comment: and it tried to do this as you said but no it doesnt work